# Populate List when web page load

Tags: asp.net

I'm a newbie in ASP.NET and I'm stuck at populating a List when web page load.

I have a class that, when instantiated, will add some objects into a list. This class has a method to add objects to a list (I made this a method because I need to reuse it later). This is the code for this class:

```
public class Task()
{
    private List<ObjectA> objList;
    ....// other variables and properties

    public Task()
    {
        objList = new List<ObjectA>();

        // first add 2 obj into the list
        AddObjToList(objList);
        AddObjToList(objList);
    }

    public void AddObjToList(List<ObjectA> objList)
    {
        bool exist = false;
        ObjectA obj = new ObjectA(); // each obj has unique properties
        foreach(var o in objList)
        {
            if(o.objName == obj.objName)
            {
                exist = true;
                break;    
            } 
        }

        if(!exist)
        {
            objList.add(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a web page that, when loaded, I want it to populate the objList with 2 starting objects. This is my code behind for the web page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task newTask = new Task();

    // the following label control is to check the number of 
    // elements in the List
    lblMSG.Text = newTask.getObjList.Count.ToString();

}
```

The problem is, when I run in debug mode, the list is populated with 2 objects just as I wanted. But when not in debug mode, when the page loaded, the label showed that the list has only 1 object. I tried to call the new Task() with isPostBack but the result is the same. What did I do wrong? What could I do to make it work?

Comment: You need to pass objList as byref instead of byvalue. Otherwise try list.add method

Comment: Should if(o.objName = obj.objName) be if(o.objName == obj.objName)?

Comment: @Khatri: I tried that too, didn't work